# Best 'order' traversal to copy a balanced binary tree into an AVL tree with minimum rotations

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I have two binary trees. One, `A` which I can access its nodes and pointers (`left`, `right`, `parent`) and `B` which I don't have access to any of its internals. The idea is to copy `A` into `B` by iterating over the nodes of `A` and doing an `insert` into `B`. `B` being an AVL tree, is there a traversal on `A` (preorder, inorder, postorder) so that there is a minimum number of rotations when inserting elements to `B`?

Edit:

- The tree `A` is balanced, I just don't know the exact implementation;
- Iteration on tree `A` needs to be done using only pointers (the programming language is C and there is no queue or stack data structure that I can make use of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebalancing in AVL happens when the depth of one part of the tree exceeds the depth of some other part of the tree by more than one.  So to avoid triggering a rebalance you want to feed nodes into the AVL tree one level at a time; that is, feed it all of the nodes from level N of the original tree before you feed it any of the nodes from level N+1.

That ordering would be achieved by a breadth-first traversal of the original tree.

---

**Edit**

OP added:

> Iteration on tree A needs to be done using only pointers (the
>   programming language is C and there is no queue or stack data
>   structure that I can make use of).

That does not affect the answer to the question as posed, which is still that a breadth-first traversal requires the fewest rebalances.

It does affect the way you will implement the breadth-first traversal.  If you can't use a predefined queue then there are several ways that you could implement your own queue in C: an array, if permitted, or some variety of linked list are the obvious choices.

If you aren't allowed to use dynamic memory allocation, and the size of the original tree is not bounded such that you can build a queue using a fixed buffer that is sized for the worst case, then you can abandon the queue-based approach and instead use recursion to visit successively deeper levels of the tree.  (Imagine a recursive traversal that stops when it reaches a specified depth in the tree, and only emits a result for nodes at that specified depth.  Wrap that recursion in a `while` or `for` loop that runs from a depth of zero to the maximum depth of the tree.)

Comment: One of the questions I have for the OP is whether the original tree is an AVL tree. If it isn't, then a level-by-level order might not be the right way to visit items - or rather, if it is the optimal solution, that would require some justification as to why no other approach is better. (Think about, say, a degenerate tree that zig-zags or is just a giant linked list.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to clarify some things. Please check the edited question.

Comment: The title of the question says the OP is starting with a balanced binary tree.

Comment: There are lots of ways to balance a tree. Most of them do not produce trees that are always balanced according to the AVL criteria.  AVL is more strict than red-black, treap, splay, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the original tree is not necessarily AVL-balanced, then you can't just copy it.

To ensure that there is no rebalancing in the new tree, you should create a *complete* binary tree, and you should insert the nodes in BFS/level order so that every intermediate tree is also complete.

A "complete" tree is one in which every level is full, except possibly the last.  Since every complete tree is AVL-balanced, and every intermediate tree is complete, there will be no rebalancing required.

If you can't copy your original tree out into an array or other data structure, then you'll need to do log(N) in-order traversals of the original tree to copy all the nodes.  During the first traversal, you select and copy the root.  During the second, you select and copy level 2.  During the third, you copy level 3, etc.

Whether or not a source node is selected for each level depends only on its index within the source tree, so the actual structure of the source tree is irrelevant.

Since each traversal takes O(N) time, the total time spent traversing is O(N log N).  Since inserts take O(log N) time, though, that is how long insertion takes as well, so doing log N traversals does not increase the complexity of the overall process.